# RegEx: Grabbing semicolon enclosed by quotation marks and at least one character

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I need a regular expression (that works in notepad++) that grabs semicolons enclosed by quotation marks and where at least one character is between the quotation mark and the semicolon.

- This semicolon should be matched: `"asdf;a3"`
- This semicolon should not be matched: `";"`

Until now I have the following regex: `\"(.*?)\"`

However, this matches everything between the quotation marks. I only need the semicolon as a match.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean one character on the left and right?  `"[^;]+(;)[^;]+` using a capturing group? Or `"[^;]+\K;(?=[^;]+")`

Comment: yes, at least one character left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) not match any of the listed characters:

```
 "[^";]+(;)[^;"]+"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BacOsE/1)

Or make use of `\K` to forget what was macthed and a positive lookahead:

```
"[^;"]+\K;(?=[^;"]+")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BacOsE/2)

To match multipe semicolons between double quotes, you could make use of `\G`

**Explanation**

```
(?:"|\G(?!^))[^";]+\K;(?=[^"]+")
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `"` Match `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^";]+` Match 1+ times not `"` or `'`
- `\K;` Forget what was matched and match `;`
- `(?=[^"]+")` Positive lookahead, assert that what is on the right is 1+ times not `"` and then match `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BacOsE/4/)

Note: if you don't want to match newlines you could add that to the character class `[^;"\r\n]`

Comment: looks good, but what if the "at least one character left and right" can also be special characters. could you expand your answer? then I think I am good.

Comment: and can you also expand on matching multiple semicolons? For example `"asdf;asdf;asdf"`.

Comment: Is also matches specials characters. The negatated character class matches those.

Comment: ah okay, yes you are right. Then my issue is only that multiple semicolons are not matched. So the 2 semicolons in `"asdf;asdf;asdf"` should be matched. is that possible?

Comment: not quite, because this matches also `";"` (even though there are no characters between `"` and `;`.

Comment: great. that seems to cover all my cases. thanks for the exceptional help. answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/.+?\;.+?/g
```

[Here](https://regexper.com/#%2F.%2B%3F%5C%3B.%2B%3F%2Fg) is a link that will help you understand the flow of this regex.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/pNWSu0/1) is link displaying the demo of this regex.